# Create if not exist PostgresSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

i have managed to write a line that says locate certain user by email and assign a role. Just wondering if there is a way to say create if not exist and specify a couple if users

```
Create if not exist -> 

<sql>
 UPDATE USERS SET ROLE = ‘ROLE_ADMIN’ WHERE EMAIL = ‘test@gmai.com’
 UPDATE USERS SET ROLE = ‘ROLE_ADMIN’ WHERE EMAIL = ‘tes1t@gmai.com’
 UPDATE USERS SET ROLE = ‘ROLE_ADMIN’ WHERE EMAIL = ‘test2@gmai.com’
</sql>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`insert ... on conflict` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT). For this to work, you need a unique or primary key constraint on column `email`. If it does not yet exist, you can create it as follows:

```
alter table users add constraint users_unique_email unique(email);
```

Then you can do:

```
insert into users (email, role)
values(
    ('test@gmai.com',  'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    ('test1@gmai.com', 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    ('test2@gmai.com', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
)
on conflict(email) do update set role = excluded.role
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am using liquidbase, 
        <addUniqueConstraint tableName="users" columnNames="email" constraintName="users_unique_email"/>

Since i have this i do not need alter table add constrain and can just insert into users(email,role) as you said